# Trouble accessing ForeignKey elements

Tags: python, django

I currently have two models set up in my Django app that have a ForeignKey relationship.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = RichTextField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date', null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments", blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField("date", blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

What I am not getting is making queries between the two.  I have tried making queries through the shell but to no success.  If I set `Post(title="Cat")` and then make `c = Comment(name="Dog")`, I can query each models respective `title` or `name` through something like `p = Post.object.get(pk=1)` and `p.title` will output `Cat`.  But if I do `p.comment` or `p.comment_id`, there is an error.  Likewise with any `Comment` objects.  However when I do `print c.post`, I get `None`. What am I missing  in order to make `p.<field_here>" =`Dog`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/

Comment: I don't see a difference from what I did compared to what the Django documentation shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have related name "comments", access to set foreign model from `Post` should be called this way:

```
p.comments
```

But since you can have many comments for a same Post, this won't return a unique value, but a related manager that you need to query. So you could get:

```
p.comments.filter(name="Dog")
```